# In "The Lottery" TV show, why did the government fire the head scientist?

Tags: the-lottery

Just to make sure there is no confusion, I am talking about the 2014 post-apocalyptic TV series *[The Lottery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Lottery_(TV_series))*, not the Shirley Jackson short story, the 80s TV show *Lottery!*, or anything else with a similar name.

In the first episode, Dr. Alison Lennon was the lead scientist of a team successfully able to create the first 100 viable human embryos after nearly 10 years of no births. As soon as she does this, Darius Hayes, director of the US Fertility Commision fires her with the intent to replace her and most of her team, but doesn't give a reason. By Dr. Lennon's own admission, more research needs to be done because she isn't sure if she can replicate the results, and presumably she would be the best person to continue her own research. Furthermore, there is no indication at that point in time that she has any distrust for the US government and that she wouldn't continue to cooperate with them going forward, so this seems to be a really bizarre and illogical reaction.

In fact by the second episode, the government has given back her job (in exchange for amnesty for a crime she committed after being fired) because they decided they needed her to continue with her research and also publicly announce to the world that she was the lead scientist of the project. In other words, the government fired her, then hired her back (even giving her amnesty as a benefit) so that she could do...exactly what she would have done had they not fired her.

Am I missing something? It seems like half the problems going on in the series so far (e.g. Dr. Lennon stealing the embryo, her distrust of the government) stem from her being fired, so it seems like a critical bit of information in the show.

So why did the government fire Dr. Lennon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dr. Lennon was shoved aside because she admitted that she wasn't going to cooperate.  The government was bringing in a new team, she said it was her lab and that she didn't have time for them.  So rather than keep her around as a troublemaker they locked her out.  The government, as represented by Darius and his evil minions, needed someone to lead the lab who was onboard with the Big Plan, whatever that is.  One thing we know for sure is that the Big Plan did not involve publicizing the breakthrough.

Dr. Lennon was rehired once the chief of staff convinced the President of her lottery idea.  Lennon was only needed as a PR spokesperson because of the upcoming announcement about the lottery.  Otherwise she was probably as good as dead.

Comment: That's the reason? Huh, I figured not wanting to train a new team was a pretty logical response given that there would be lost productivity due to bringing everyone up to speed. If that one objection was supposed to express that she was a "troublemaker", it really didn't come across that way to me. That said, I disagree with your second paragraph that she was only needed for PR because she was doing research in episode 2.